# Does Google Assistant API update automatically on voice kit?

Tags: networking

I have a Google voice kit, and after setting it up, I realized that certain features hadn't been added to the Google Assistant API. I was wondering if, when a new update is released, it would update to the newest version of the API since it's always connected to the internet, or whether I would need to replace assistant.json again with the new API?